# Timecircles trigger click on 0

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using Timecircles to build a simple quiz. Inside the "click" function I use .getTime() to get the actual time it took for the user to pick an answare.

However, I would like to "autoclick" (trigger the click-action) if the value of the time is 0. In order to move on to next question and set the number of points etc.

```
$(".countdown").TimeCircles({
    count_past_zero: false,
    total_duration: 15
    }).addListener(function(unit,value,total) {
        if(value == 0){
            alert ('GAME OVER!');
            //Trigger the click event here
        }
});
$('#quiz-container').on('click', '.my_button', function() {
    var t = $(".countdown").TimeCircles().getTime();
    //Quiz logic here

    // Load new question and reset timer
    var t = $(".countdown").TimeCircles().reset();
});
```

I can not place the click-function in the actual addlistener as I need to refresh it for each new question.

Comment: Extract the functionality of the click handler in another function then you can call it from both places.

Comment: If the answer didnt work, or you meant something else let me know so I can help

Comment: I have created a new function called quizLogic:
<code>
jQuery.fn.quizLogic = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
       alert('Function work');
    });
};
</code>
and I can trigger it with:
**$('#quiz-container').trigger('click').quizLogic();**

However, how should the **$('#quiz-container').on('click', '.my_button', function() {** look

Comment: @user3419021, can you replicate it in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) like

```
$('#quiz-container').trigger('click');
```

or the shorthand form

```
$('#quiz-container').click();
```

So, you will have

```
$(".countdown").TimeCircles({
    count_past_zero: false,
    total_duration: 15
    }).addListener(function(unit,value,total) {
        if(value == 0){
            alert ('GAME OVER!');
            //Trigger the click event here
            $('#quiz-container').click();
        }
});
```